# Finding the right solver

Tags: matlab, optimization, constraints, nonlinear-optimization

I need to solve the following non-linear problem with constraints but I am not sure to use the appropriate function and solver as changing from the algorithm: 'interior-point' to 'sqp' give different answers. Could you help first to make sure fmincon is the most appropriate function here and also if the options should be set up in a different way to ensure that the optimization does not stop too early. I have tried to set up: 'MaxFunctionEvaluations' to 1000000 and 'MaxIterations'to 10000 and this helps but the time required increases as well dramatically.

w is a vector whose values have to be optimized.
scores is a vector of the same size as w.

the size if w and scores is usually between 10 and 40.

Here is the optimization setup:

objective function: sum(log(abs(w)));

linear inequalities1: w_i > 0 if scores_i > 0

linear inequalities2: w_i < 0 if scores_i < 0

non-linear equalities1: sum(abs(w)) = 1

non-linear inequalities1: sqrt(w * sigma * w') <= 0.1

Here is my code:

```
N = numel(scores);

%%%LINEAR EQUALITIES CONSTRAINTS
Aeq = [];
beq = [];

%%%LINEAR INEQUALITIES CONSTRAINTS
temp = ones(0,N);
temp(scores >= 0) = -1;
temp(scores < 0) = 1;
A = diag(temp);
b = zeros(N,1);

%%%BOUNDs CONSTRAINTS
lb = [];
ub = [];

w0 = ones(1,N)/N;
nonlcon = @(w)nonlconstr(w,sigma,tgtVol);
options = optimoptions('fmincon','Algorithm','interior-point','MaxFunctionEvaluations',1000000,'MaxIterations',10000);
%options = optimoptions('fmincon','Algorithm','interior-point','OptimalityTolerance',1e-7);

[w,fval,exitflag,output] = fmincon(@(w)objectfun(w),w0,A,b,Aeq,beq,lb,ub,nonlcon,options);

function [c,ceq] = nonlconstr(w,sigma,tgtVol)
      c = sqrt(w*sigma*w') - tgtVol;
      ceq = sum(abs(w)) - 1;
end

function  f = objectfun(w)
    f = sum(-log(abs(w)));
end
```

Comment: Warning: `abs()` is non-differentiable. I always try to reformulate things to get rid of this. See [here](http://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2016/11/reformulation-of-non-differentiable-term.html) for a recent example. I suspect your problem to be non-convex (this may be another reason why different solvers give different solutions).

Comment: Thank you for this insight. I think i somehow understand the way to go. But then, if I have N variables when using the absolute value, getting rid of it would mean having 3*N variables. I would get for each w_i an additional w_i+ and w_i- . Is that correct?

Comment: I think this can be done without variable splitting in this case: you know the sign of $w_i$ from the data.

Comment: Yes that is a very good point. So now we got a linear objective function, would it make sense to use another matlab function which deals with linear objectif function to speed up the optimization maybe?

Comment: To my knowledge there are no NLP solvers that can exploit linear objectives. There are however efficient solvers that can deal with quadratic terms in the constraints (especially when convex). Not as a built-in Matlab function I am afraid.